# How to recognize shape from 4 equally distant lines

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

If I have a random shape and I draw 8 lines through it like this (for the circle for example):
[image: Example]

Now here comes the problem for me: You dont really know the starting position of the lines. for example for a square it can start at the corner or a bit after that. But the lines will ALWAYS have the same distance between then.

So with those information with the knowledge of each line's length is there a way to "recognize" a shape OR to find out if it a cube at the very least?

Comment: You mean a square? Suggest you draw a couple of cases and see what patterns you can spot. Post pictures if you do.

Comment: will try to do some self research on that and see if I can get it done..

Comment: "But the lines will ALWAYS have the same distance between then": what does this mean ?There is no distance between secant lines.

Comment: i mean that all lines together will make the same shape they do in the picture i posted